updating 32bit macro for 64bit
This excel macro worked fine on windows 10, but gives me errors on windows 11. If anyone could help would really appreciate it.
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

'~~> This is where the images will be saved. Change as applicable
Const FolderName As String = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Images\"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String

    '~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
        strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"

        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "HI-Five"
        Else
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "SAD FACE"
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox "Images Downloaded!!!"
End Sub

this section are in red as errors
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long


Which version  of Excel do you use? 32bit or 64bit. Also check this link

windows 11 64 bit

@Gary Brace: Please check the Excel version as shown in the link I posted.

Do you mean that you used the above code in Windows 10 32 bit?

@GarryBrace please make note that it's possible to run Office 32 bit on Windows 11 64 bit - important to not confuse the 2

I was using the above code in windows 10 32bit and it worked, but no longer works in windows 11 64bit.

You did not answer my clarification question...
Please, use the next API declaration, able to work in both versions (32 - 64bit):
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
        ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If

Public Const BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION As Long = &H10

And call the API function as:
  Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, 0)

